# How can I create a Filter/Search dropdown list attribute in Ember? Handlebar Syntax Required

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember. Would like to understand as to how can I implement a Search/Filter dropdown in Ember like one below in JS.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
</div>
```

And JS would look like this

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         a[i].style.display = "";
      }
      else {
         a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

Just need help with the Handlebar Syntax in Template.

Answer (score 1):

While using Ember.js, you shouldn't modify DOM. Let ember does that.
So you need to handle `onkeyup` event in your component and filter the values.

I've prepared a twiddle for you, please see: [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a166853bfd85edb66bba8196eae7681e?openFiles=components.menu-component.js%2C)

In this twiddle, I put every link definitions into the component.js as json definition. I could also use template.hbs to check whether any link was filtered or not.

By the way, please check the current ember add-ons that might help to you: [emberobserver.com](https://www.emberobserver.com) For example [ember-power-select](https://ember-power-select.com/docs/the-list) might help you.